# Case When function inclusion vs. exclusion for formula(numeric) saved search

Tags: netsuite

So I attempted to modify an existing search to fit my needs and I am trying to figure out how to include vs. exclude certain wording to match the two criteria. As you can see in the User Notes search, the wording "new proof sent" should only be included in the results for "new proof" and not "proof sent". I only want the count for "proof sent" if the word new is not included. So I tried to have the search meet "new proof" without the word sent, to differentiate between "proof sent" and "new proof sent" [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjeIm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY7wz.png)

However, as you can see from the count, the statement "new proof sent" counts for both results, "new proof" and "proof sent" columns. Is there a way to separate the two?

Answer (score 0):

@KenHPG, have you considered restructuring your CASE WHEN ELSE?
You have a specific case for your PROOF SENT formula when you want it to be 0...when 'NEW PROOF' is found.

so maybe adding something like:

```
CASE WHEN INSTR(UPPER({field}), 'NEW PROOF') = 1
THEN 0
ELSE WHEN INSTR(UPPER({field}), 'PROOF SENT') = 0
THEN 0
ELSE 1
END
```

That way you are specifying all the cases when you want the count to be zero:

1. 'NEW PROOF' is found
2. 'PROOF SENT' is not found.